# Forgot iCloud Keychain password while updating iOS on iPhone 6s Plus

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, ios, icloud, password

I'm updating iOS on my iPhone 6s Plus, and forgot my iCloud Keychain passcode.

It gives me two options:

- reset keychain
- approve from other device

The first option will erase all my passwords stored on my devices, which isn't acceptable.

The second option is unavailable. I tried to reset my passcode, but it can only send it to my phone - which cannot receive any messages.

I tried to go to iCloud > Account details and reset from there, but it requests the passcode right after the password.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no way to regain access to your iCloud keychain if you don't have access to your passcode or any other devices associated with your keychain. You'll most likely have to reset your keychain.

In the future, consider using a password manager like LastPass or KeePass.

Comment: +1 for suggesting password manager. I also suggest 1Password, it's served me great for years.

Answer (score 0):

You could try calling Apple. If there is another way to authenticate yourself, it is possible that they will help. (You mentioned other devices, so it is possible that they can set up another of your devices to allow it to approve resetting the iCloud keychain passcode.) For obvious reasons, Apple does not publish the rules about what they will and will not do. But if you're desperate, it's worth a call.